# Adjust annotation position of a scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a scatter plot + annotation like this:

[image]

I annotated each dot with this code:

```
for i, txt in enumerate(labels):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i], y[i]), 
            fontproperties=cur_font, 
            ha='center',
            va='top',
            fontsize=14)
```

As you can see from the figure about, the text overlaps with the pie chart. I can do `y[i] - 0.05` to hack around this issue. But I would like to know if there is a way to automatically calculate the `0.05` part so that the code adapts to any x & y input.

Code for drawing the circles:

`draw_scatter_pie` is called first, then it calls `draw_pie` to draw each pie chart.

```
def draw_pie(
    dist: List[float], xpos: float, ypos: float, size: float, ax  # pie各个slice的大小占比
) -> None:

    # for incremental pie slices
    cumsum = np.cumsum(dist)
    cumsum = cumsum / cumsum[-1]
    pie = [0] + cumsum.tolist()

    counter = 0

    # draw each pie slices
    # for my data, there are only two slices for each pie chart
    for r1, r2 in zip(pie[:-1], pie[1:]):
        angles = np.linspace(2 * np.pi * r1, 2 * np.pi * r2)
        x = [0] + np.cos(angles).tolist()
        y = [0] + np.sin(angles).tolist()

        xy = np.column_stack([x, y])
        ax.scatter(
            xpos,
            ypos,
            marker=xy,
            s=size,
            facecolor=("indigo" if counter == 0 else "#CDCDCD"),
        )
        counter += 1


def draw_scatter_pie(
    x: List[float],
    y: List[float],
    pie_size: List[float],
    labels: List[str],
    size: float,
    display_axis=True,
    adjust_y = 0
) -> None:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 10))
    for i in range(len(x)):
         # for my data, there are only two slices for each pie chart
        p_size = [pie_size[i], 1 - pie_size[i]]
        draw_pie(p_size, x[i], y[i], size, ax)

    for i, txt in enumerate(labels):
        ax.annotate(
            txt,
            (x[i], y[i] - adjust_y), # want to adjust the y position of each annotation
            fontproperties=cur_font,
            ha="center",
            va="top",
            fontsize=14,
        )

    ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(display_axis)
    ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(display_axis)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: How about taking a percentage: 0.99*y[i]

Comment: @Sheldore since y[i] are different, the larger the value, the more 0.99*y[i] will produce, thus, the gap will be different for every y value

Comment: You give no clue how you produced the plot and especially how the circles are defined. Of course the general rule would be to add or substract exactly the radius from the y coordinates.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Just updated the post with drawing code

Comment: `annotate(..., xy=(x[i], y[i]), xytext=(0,-np.sqrt(size)/2), textcoords="offset points",..)` ?